# Do the rules for Creatures creation for the Star Trek RPG by Decipher really make them weak?

Tags: house-rules, star-trek, star-trek-decipher

The rules given in the books, whether in the Narrator's Guide or the Creatures supplement, are a mess. But, as far as I can tell, creatures created with the rules from the Narrator's Guide look ridiculously feeble, and require tens of thousands of XP to become equivalent to the creatures depicted in the eponymous supplement in terms of stats.

I've looked online, including on [Beyond the Final Frontier](http://strpg.patrickgoodman.org/), but I couldn't find anything about the creatures: no errata or even someone doing an homebrew system.

Did I miss something in the original rules or in Creatures?

This question is not about the card game but the [RPG that Decipher](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Roleplaying_Game_(Decipher)) created after they got the license.

Comment: Since folks are marking this for closure as off-topic, I suspect you need to create a tag for [*Star Trek Role-playing Game*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Roleplaying_Game) or whatever system this question is asking about. I'd do it myself, but I'm not sure which one you're using, and I'm unfamiliar with *Star Trek* RPGs anyway. (I think the close folks may think this is about Decipher's *Star Trek* trading card game!) Also… you may be [shopping!](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7413/8610) (You can ask which book has *official* resources for more challenging monsters, though.)

Comment: I added a precision that I'm looking for resources for the RPG, not the card game. And I'm not shopping, already got the books, but looking for some sort of homebrew system for creature creation, if one exist, else I'll keep on winging them.

Comment: The problem is this phrase: "So I'm a taker for any homebrew creation system for creatures that makes a little bit more sense than the original rules. Or a way to fix the rules if that's even possible." That's going to—fairly or unfairly—strike folks as a shopping question because it implies *anything* is acceptable so voting's impossible. Narrow that! I suggest making this into an actual question like *Creatures in published supplements seem incredibly weak. [Provide an example.] Am I misreading these entries?* then leaving it to answers to propose solutions.

Comment: That is, you may be getting ahead of the problem. *You* have already evaluated all the creatures, found them lacking, and need a solution. However, other folks may have evaluated all the creatures, found them acceptable, and don't *need* a solution. Why not let those folks tell you what—if anything—you may have missed?

Comment: Good comment, I changed it following your advice.